# Apply a large Matrix on QR decomposed

Tags: c++, eigen

I have to convert the MATLAB code to C++ on eigen library,but I have some problems at QR decomposed, matlab has a function:

```
[Q,R]=qr(A,0); // A is m-by-n
```

It produces the economy-size decomposition.If `m>n`,only the first `n` columns of `Q` and the first `n` rows of `R` are computed. If `m<=n`,this is the same as `[Q,R]=qr(A)`.

I have tried to compute it on eigen library. But the `A` is `20000x1000`, so there is always a application crash at QR decomposed.And I don't know how to produce the economy-size decomposition on eigen or other ways.

How can I convert `[Q,R]=qr(A,0)` to C++/Eigen?

Comment: Did you debug why it crashes? And could you provide the C++ code you used for reference?

Comment: Because the Q is 20000x20000.It's too large.I need to produce the economy-size decomposition.

Comment: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=569 (first result for »economy-size decomposition eigen«)

Comment: @Darklighter Thanks,it's correct!

Comment: Does that solve your problem? And can post it as an answer.

Comment: You usually don't need to store `Q` inside a `MatrixXd` at all, unless you need to inspect certain elements, or maybe want to apply it to very many vectors (more than the number of cols of `A`). Otherwise, applying the householder vectors directly will be more efficient (both time and memory) than constructing `Q`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MatrixXd A(m,n);    
HouseholderQR<MatrixXd> qr;  
qr.compute(A);  
temp= qr.matrixQR().triangularView<Upper>();  
Q= qr.householderQ() * Eigen::MatrixXd::Identity(m, n); 
R=temp.topRows(n);
```